# Any way for Java Print to ignore lpoptions?

Tags: java, linux, printing, debian, cups

I'm using the javax.print API to print a Jasper Report on Debian Linux. For some reason the saved lpoptions (CUPS settings) always override settings choosen on the Java Print dialog. At this point the only way I am getting around this problem is to delete the .lpoptions file in the user's directory. Is there a way to get javax.print to ignore the saved lpoptions?

Comment: @user unknown: Thanks, so the question was removed. Removed my comment as well...

Answer (score 0):

Java does not know what lpoptions is. The Java application is printing using your it's own settings, but the Unix is overwriting the options using the Cups settings.

So the question should be:

*Any way for Unix ignore lpoptions and let Java do it's job?*

I thing you should ask it again at unix.stackexchange.com with a new title.